# How to get Authorization Token

Tags: api, security

I secured my Web Api using Token Based authentication. All works well, but for now before making an api call, I request for a token by making separate api call which will return me the token for making further request. What I am wondering is there any possible way that I can generate token on client side which will be decrypted on the server?
OR
What you think, I am on the right track?

Here is my jQuery Code

```
  $.when($.get("/api/service/GetToken"))
                .done(function (token) {

                    doAjaxCall("GET", "/api/service/GetAllJobsStatusCount/1/admin", "{}", "json", token, function (data) {

                        console.log(data);
                    });

                });
```

Here is my method which will return me token

```
[Api.HttpGet]
        public string GetToken()
        {
            var authorizeToken = "apikey";
            return Rsa.Encrypt(authorizeToken);
        }
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single token only works for authentication if an encrypted connection (HTTPS) is used - otherwise, MITMs can read the token and steal the identity. If everything is done using secure connections, it doesn't matter who calculates the token, as long as it is exchanged before any authentications, so both partners know it beforehand - otherwise there would be no way to know if it's valid or not. Note however that the token can always only prove that the client is the one that the token was given to (or recevied from) in the first place, you still don't know anything else (for example if the other person was who he claimed when te exchange was made).

If not using secure connections, I'd suggest using public-key encryption. If not encrypting the whole request, calculate a signature and sign it with the private key clientside, verify it server-side. In this case, the client MUST calculate the private and the public key and hand the public key over to the server, as the server should never know the client's private key (and it shouldn't ever be sent over a unencrypted connection either, after all that'S the whole point of using PKI).

For another approach (that is widely used, but not extraordinary secure), see OAuth.

[Edit]: Addition based on comment:

To verify a client, every request that accesses valuable data has to be authenticated. That means: the client needs to send something that is able to prove that it is who it claims to be along with EVERY request (as HTTP is a stateless protocol).

The usual way is to exchange some secret once, that is valid for either a limited time or forever, and only known to the client and the servet. That way, the server can verify idientities by checking if the client sent the token it was given. Expiring tokens after improves security, but when a client requests a knew one, there is no way to tell if it is the same client that used the old one (unless the request is validated by the old token and that one is still valid).
If ther client calculates the token, that deosn'T change anything - it sends it once and tells the server who it is, then every request that carries the same token does most likely come from the same client. There is only one additional thing the server has to do here: If two clients calculate the same token, the server has to reject the token from the second client and request another one. Otherwise, clients cannot be distinguished anymore.

Comment: So, all I have to do to enable https. Right?

Comment: ....and disable http. Yes. Of course you'd need a certificate for https, and self-signed certificates as well as most free ones will get rejected by the browser (most likely silently when using AJAX, but not sure about that) - so maybe you'll have to buy one if you don't own one already. CHeapest ones are ~100-200$ a year.

Comment: PKI is still more secure though, as the secrets stay valid and secure even if your server gets attacked and public keys stolen. If only using single tokens, they all get compromised when stolen)

Comment: Thank you very much for you valuable suggestion.

Comment: Just to be confirm one more time, Is it right that I am asking an authorization token from the server before making further request?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46709/discussion-between-user2866746-and-johannes-h)